# C#, usage of custom exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-core, .net-standard

I need to make a short premise: I am a software architect with more than 20 years of experience, not a junior asking directions. This is not to say "I know it all" (quite the contrary in fact) but just to give context and state that I have come across a legitimate doubt about something I thought was common knowledge and best practice and have done so for all this time.

I am working on different projects for different clients. I always check method's parameters for not being null and for other non valid states. A common precondition check you can find in my code is:

```
if (param == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param)); }
```

or

```
this.myField = myParam ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myParam));
```

Also bear in mind that I use exceptions sparingly, I do not do user input validation with exceptions, I just use them to check and/or signal invalid states in the code, thus programming errors. It's extremely rare to find a try/catch block in my code at all.

One of my clients just asked me, without much margin to debate, to replace any similar occurrence with the use of custom exceptions. Meaning I am to define a CustomerNameArgumentNullException, CustomerNameFileNotFoundException, etc. and use those wherever I would use a standard exception.

Now I will comply, I have no right to debate the client request, but their lead programmer was pretty strong about this point on how this is the right way to go, that using default exceptions makes code less readable and also that custom exceptions make more easy to see what-is-what in Azure Application Insights. I tried to point out that he has the fully qualified name of the method that raised the exception so he can know which program, in which assembly and namespace and such but again, there was not much room to debate and it was not my place to do so.

So I've been wondering if he's actually right and I've been doing exceptions wrong all this time. If anyone has some more insight and/or some material I can read about that supports this theory.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you're absolutely right, and their lead is wrong. It's explicitly in the MS guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#use-the-predefined-net-exception-types

Comment: This sounds like a great argument for making code less maintainable and more prone to promoting job security.

Comment: And I would argue you *do* have the right to debate the client request, and that it's actually your *responsibility* to push back on bad practice - that provides value beyond just the coding.

Comment: @JonSkeet I usually do, but this is the lead architect of a very big company, I already pointed out how weird it is, but I can't push it. I always propose myself as "I can give you all the advice I think is right, but in the end it's your call as it's gonna be your codebase". I don't think my approach is wrong. I hope at least.

Comment: I think you definitely have the right to make your case, pointing at the Microsoft documentation (and they should at least then accept that what they're doing goes against the Microsoft guidance) - but then accept their final say (and consider moving on from them as a client, if you get to pick and choose).

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you Jon, every feedback is appreciated but yours in particular means a great deal. I'm ok witht his client, their lead programmer follows best practices for about almost anything else, there is just this weird thing. Since he's the one that always points out MS standards and how he often talks to MS developers about code guidelines I thought he knew something I didn't. Thank you again.

Comment: If he's keen on referring to MS guidance, that puts you in a *particularly* strong position. He may not be aware of the guidance at the moment, but at least it gives a possibility that he might rethink.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While normally I'd suggest that a question like this should be closed as opinion-based, in this case there's [*really* clear guidance from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#use-the-predefined-net-exception-types):

> ## Use the predefined .NET exception types
>
> Introduce a new exception class only when a predefined one doesn't apply. For example:
>
> - Throw an `InvalidOperationException` exception if a property set or method call is not appropriate given the object's current state.
> - Throw an `ArgumentException` exception or one of the predefined classes that derive from `ArgumentException` if invalid parameters are passed.

In other words, your customer is asking you to go against guidance from the platform authors.

You may not be able to change the customer's mind to follow the guidance, but you can be confident that your approach is the recommended one, and their approach goes against that.

Following conventions like this is particularly important in Open Source projects - it's one thing to decide that you'll have your own conventions when only your team will work with the code, but if an application uses 10 different Open Source libraries, each of which has decided to create its own conventions, that's a nightmare.

Comment: I can't agree more. I'm all for standards, and using different standards for different languages. Javascript wants camelCase methods while C# want PascalCase methods for instance. Thank you for clearing this up, even though it really did not need any clearing ^^

Answer (score 1):

There are two sides of the coin. Sure MS recommends [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#use-the-predefined-net-exception-types)

Using custom exceptions gives you some advantages and disadvantages.

Advantages:

1. Abstraction
2. You can log telemetry data before you raise an exception. If not for custom exceptions, you'd have to catch an exception, log data and re-throw.
3. Customizing exception and error handling as needed by the app/services, etc

Disadvantages:

1. Telemetry data will have no stack trace if you are throwing custom exceptions.
2. Code maintenance and rigorous testing

There are various other things that come into picture, but catching an exception, logging metrics and then re-throwing (to preserve stack trace) the same exception is expensive.

Just my thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand disadvantage 1.  How will you ever have a situation where you don't have a stack trace when throwing a new exception?  An exception, custom or MS-provided, is still just that...an exception.  It doesn't change its nature by being defined within your codebase.

Comment: An example might be.. a database exception that is propagated to the code and you have a custom exception for that. You'd throw the custom exception but the underlying stack trace is vanished (unless you attach it all in which case custom exceptions are moot).

Comment: In either case I'd argue that is incorrect.

If you have a custom exception, it typically means that you want to change the nature of what is being returned. You should be logging the original exception at the site of the catch before rethrowing anything new, including the original exception in your custom exception.  That way your stack trace is already captured and is also preserved up the stack.

Comment: If you catch an exception and throw a custom one you should be adding the original exception as the inner exception of the custom one thus maintaining the entire stack trace.

Comment: @juharr Not necessarily IMO. Custom exceptions are meant to handle exceptions differently and you may or may not want to bubble up everything.

Comment: @DavidL I get your point and my example was a bad one

Comment: I'd argue that even in custom exception you should never swallow anything and always bubble up everything. It's not any exception responsibility to handle and/or hide what transpired in the inner exception.